# Exporting list of Feature Classes to CSV using ArcPy and Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, export, csv

I am successfully using the follow script

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
env.workspace = ("WORKSPACE")
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcList
```

to export feature class names from a workspace.

I'd like to export the results to a CSV file (creating a simple one column list of Feature Class names); I've looked into the Python help guide but am struggling with the syntax and where to place the csv.writer and import csv functions.

How do I get the results to be written to a csv file?

Answer (score 8):

Why not something like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import csv
import os
env.workspace = ("WORKSPACE")
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
with open('codes.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(fcList)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should look something like this:

```
import csv, arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/temp/mygeo.gdb"

    with open('C:\\temp\\test.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
       csv_writer.writerow(('Name'))

       fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
          for f in fclist:
             csv_writer.writerow(f)
```

Comment: The feature class name returned in the for loop should be passed as array [f] into csv_writer.writerow

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at the scripts referenced in [Working with Microsoft Excel in ArcGIS Desktop](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/10/working-with-microsoft-excel-in-arcgis-desktop/) and the updated ArcGIS 10 script referenced in this [ESRI forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35206-ArcGIS-10-export-to-Excel).

Both scripts contain "fallback" methods (python code) for exporting to CSV.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this with this way:

```
# Your code

import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 


env.workspace = ("WORKSPACE")
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#print fcList

# Open a new file 
f = open("C:\Temp\newFile.txt", 'w')

# Loop feature class
for fc in fcList:
    f.write(str(row.getValue("id")) + ", " + str(row.getValue("name")) + ", " + 
           str(row.getValue("others")) + "\n")

f.close()
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I've had a test of the code above but come across invalid syntax in the last line - f.close() -

Comment: there must be whitespace problem with f.close(), otherwise there should not be any trouble. open and close methods are at the same indentation level...

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import csv
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Geodatabase.gdb"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
with open('FeatureClassList.csv', 'wb') as f:
    var = csv.writer(f)
    for row in fcList:
        var.writerow([row])
print "Done"
```

I had some issues with the other solutions offered here and was able to address them with my above code. I wanted each feature class to be listed in a row not as a column so I had to make up loop for each row.